# foreach loop image display horizontal

Tags: php, html, css, foreach, instagram

I just had a previous question about this script, and now I'm back again because it's displaying vertically.

Basically, what I want this to do is display three photos per line, so there will be two rows of 3 images, totaling at 6 images.

```
<div class="4u">
  <article class="item"  style="float: left;">
    <?PHP foreach($photoData->data as $img){
    echo '<a href="'.$img->link.'?intent=like" target="_blank"><img src="'.$img->images->thumbnail->url.'"/></a>';
    echo '<header>'.$img->caption->text.'</header>';}
    ?>
  </article>
</div>
```

The program I'm building is an Instagram fetcher that fetches 6 of my most recent photos from Instagram, and works, but here's the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgTBW.png
Now, clearly I zoomed out because I wanted to show you all of the images.
I've tried `float: left`, and it didn't work.

Anyone have any ideas? I'd love the help. Thank you. :)

Here's a JSFiddle of how I'd like it to go
http://jsfiddle.net/GZb8A/

Comment: Add a counter and if statement.. If count reaches 3, add a <br/> and reset counter to 0 or 1 however you want to start

Comment: Try posting your CSS and if possible create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: LJ, do you know how I would go about doing this? Sorry, I'm new to PHP.

Mike, I'll be working on that now.

Comment: Mike, http://jsfiddle.net/GZb8A/ Obviously, it looks better on the site, but this was a quick mockup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a line-break `<br>` to move to new line, do this:

```
<article class="item"> // no styles

<?php
$column_count = 0;
foreach($photoData->data as $img) {
    $column_count++;

    // adjust width and height in styles to suit your content better
    <div class="instagram_item" style="width:200px; height:225px; text-align:center; display:inline-block; margin:0 10px 10px 0;">

        echo '<a href="'.$img->link.'?intent=like" target="_blank">';
            echo '<img src="'.$img->images->thumbnail->url.'"/>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '<header>'.$img->caption->text.'</header>';

    </div>

    if ($column_count == 3) {
        $column_count = 0;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
?>

</article>
```

Comment: This is same as mine :) hehe

Comment: @LJ-C Posted at the same time, nice!

Comment: I noticed Cody was using elements from HTML5, so I used `<br>` instead of `<br/>` - not that it makes much difference - I'm just showing off [smug face] :)

Comment: @CodyLeeK. Nice one, good luck with the rest. Do me favour and delete all your above comments. I'll do the same. Extended comments are frowned upon :)

Answer (score 0):

You could close and open your tag in **foreach** statement like:

```
<article class="item"  style="float: left;">
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach($photoData->data as $img) {
 $count++;
 echo '<a href="'.$img->link.'?intent=like" target="_blank"><img src="'.$img->images->thumbnail->url.'"/></a>';
 echo '<header>'.$img->caption->text.'</header>';
 if(count>3) {
  // close and open article
  ?>
  </article>
  <article class="item"  style="float: left;">
  <?php
  $count = 0; //Reset count to 0 edited by LJ_C
 }
}
?>
</article>
```

Comment: your counter is off, on the second round your counter will count = 2 on the first go around, you need to set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP 
$counter = 0;
foreach($photoData->data as $img){
$counter++;
echo '<a href="'.$img->link.'?intent=like" target="_blank"><img src="'.$img->images->thumbnail->url.'"/></a>';
echo '<header>'.$img->caption->text.'</header>';
if ($counter == 3){
    echo "<br/>";
    $counter = 0;}
}?>
```

This should work

Comment: This just displays the same 6 images under the first set of images. :l
Nevermind, fixed it.

Comment: If you want it under the category as well use Ignacio Ocampo solution at the bottom